# Quality of embedded bitmaps using eps2pdf

Tags: graphics, epstopdf

I am compiling a single file using REVTEX 4.1. My image files are .eps files, and epstopdf is converting them on compilation. I load the following packages,

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

and this all works fine, except for the quality of bitmaps embedded in the images is terrible. They appear to be heavily compressed. I suspect I need to set an option for epstopdf, but I don't know what. I tried

```
\epstopdfsetup{quality=100}
```

and got the error Package keyval Error: quality undefined. This;

http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/epstopdf.pdf

has no mention of quality.

This is not something I can render using a vector based format. Also, eps is the preferred format for this particular journal. Can anyone help?

Edited to add: I use CorelDraw, and export an .eps. If I inspect the .eps by loading it back into CorelDraw, it looks fine. if I inspect the eps-converted-to.pdf in a similar way, it looks very bad. See below - left is before epstopdf, right is after.

[image: graphs of different quality]

Edited further to add:

The following link: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3025 reccomends the following;

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.pdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{`epstopdf --gsopt="-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -sColorImageFilter=FlateEncode -sGrayImageFilter=FlateEncode -sCompressPages=false -dPreserveHalftoneInfo=true" #1}
```

This is not a solution I fully understand, and in any case, it doesn't work - epstopdf fails to run at all. The solution further down the page:

```
\epstopdfsetup{update,prepend,verbose,suffix=-generated} % use suffix because you don't want to accidentally overwrite a file that might have been a pdf source. The epstopdf package manual has more on that.

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.pdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{epstopdf --gsopt="-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -sColorImageFilter=FlateEncode -sGrayImageFilter=FlateEncode -sCompressPages=false -dPreserveHalftoneInfo=true" #1 --outfile=\OutputFile}
```

sends the compilation into an unbreakable loop of some kind. I'm using TeXnicCenter, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I believe, this is not a real problem with the `epstopdf` command or package. It is rather connected to the fact, that bitmap graphics scales terribly. How did you create your image files?

Comment: If it is a bitmap, why are you saving it as an EPS in the first place? Why not PNG or JPG?

Comment: There are other components of the diagram for which a vector format is appropriate.

Comment: can you export to pdf from coral draw, rather than converting the eps?

Comment: @NLambert: I agree with daleif's statement: It should be saved in `png` or `jpg` or directly to `pdf` format, however, it remains a bitmap format in the first two cases

Comment: The journal's preferred file format is .eps. Interestingly, the same problem occurs with \psfig. This must be fixable!

Comment: @NLambert: I do not suppose that any of your editings above did improve the quality of that images, but deal with converting the `eps` file 'on-the-fly'? Why is it not possible to save your images in a vector format?

Comment: `epstopdf` is just a wrapper for ghostscript and does not change the quality at all. Also you can convert the file manually with ghostscript, e.g.: `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress file.eps file.pdf`. But I suspect this is more an issue with the PDF viewer showing bitmaps than a conversion issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I cracked it. The link I cite in my question actually explains this, once I took the trouble to read it properly.

The following is added to the preamble after \include{epstopdf};

```
\epstopdfsetup{update,prepend,verbose,suffix=-generated} % use suffix because you don't want to accidentally overwrite a file that might have been a pdf source. The epstopdf package manual has more on that.
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.pdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{epstopdf --gsopt="-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -sColorImageFilter=FlateEncode -sGrayImageFilter=FlateEncode -sCompressPages=false -dPreserveHalftoneInfo=true" #1 --outfile=\OutputFile}
```

and the following MUST be added to the output profile/command line when running latex.

```
"--enable-write18"
```

Hope that is of use to someone else.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I did not understood all the options you used but it works very well. It should be added as a native option to the epstopdf package ...

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of hours as a n00b trying to tackle this problem before realising I don't need this intermediate step of EPS as I once thought (SVG in inkscape exported as > EPS autoconverted to > PDF).

I now make all figures in inkscape, and export directly as PDF. To overcome this past mistake quickly, one can follow the Windows batch file instructions to convert a folder from svg to pdf https://gist.github.com/JohannesDeml/779b29128cdd7f216ab5000466404f11

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome also! You're quite right, the problem can be dodged by using different formats. But a significant number of journals strongly prefer EPS files for submission.

Comment: Luckily, it's relatively easy to convert svg to eps using inkscape or inkscape batch. I just thought I had to use eps for LaTeX for some reason.